# How can I pass all port traffic to local host machine?

Tags: ssl, redirect, port, loopback, tunnel

I am currently trying to redirect specific outgoing port traffic back to specific port on local loopback using netsh commands. If there is a better way to do this, any guidance would be appreciated. As of right now, I am currently trying to use something along the lines of:

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3000 connectport=102 connectaddress=127.0.0.1

What I am wanting to happen is for all traffic outbound on port  to be redirected back to the loopback address port . I will need to make every machine that connects to my server redirect the specified port / traffic back to the local loopback address. I hope that makes sense, any suggestions of a better way to do this would be appreciated be it via python, powershell. Thank you in advance!